# AngularJS - Compare & Replace objects between 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following 2 arrays `$scope.oldArray` & `$scope.newArray`

```
$scope.oldArray = [{
    "status": "New",
    "priority_summary": "High",
    "u_id" : 1
}, {
    "status": "New",
    "priority_summary": "High",
    "u_id" : 2
}, {
    "status": "New",
    "priority_summary": "High",
    "u_id" : 3
}, {
    "status": "New",
    "priority_summary": "High",
    "u_id" : 4
}];

$scope.newArray = [{
    "status": "Old",
    "priority_summary": "Low",
    "u_id" : 1
}, {
    "status": "Old",
    "priority_summary": "High",
    "u_id" : 2
}, {
    "status": "New",
    "priority_summary": "Low",
    "u_id" : 3
}, {
    "status": "New",
    "priority_summary": "High",
    "u_id" : 4
}];
```

Here I need to compare these 2 arrays, then delete the changed object in `$scope.oldArray` & add the changed object from `$scope.newArray` to `$scope.oldArray`.

Note: Should not replace all the values from `$scope.newArray` to `$scope.oldArray`.

Answer (score 1):

objects of arrays to compare can use angular.forEach

```
     angular.forEach(oldArray , function(value1, key1) {
            angular.forEach(newArray , function(value2, key2) {
                if (!(value1.status == value2.status&& 
                    value1.priority_summary==value2.priority_summary 
                    && value1.u_id==value2.u_id)) {
                    value1.status=value2.status;
                    value1.priority_summary=value2.priority_summary;
                    value1.u_id=value2.u_id;
                }
            });
    });
```